# How can I Resize GIF Banner for Google Ads?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, google

I have the following animation which is simple shapes and colors, no gradients or images. But i cannot resize it under 150 k (Google limit)
Any suggestions?
Thank you [image]

Comment: 150KB is going to be tough for what you have there. You might have to shorten or drop some animations. That said, you might be able to get to 150KB with https://ezgif.com/optimize by first dropping every second frame and then applying lossy compression. The way it works is you upload the image, choose optimization method from the dropdown below and if you want to optimize it more, you click "optimize" in the menu below the optimized gif.

Comment: And if you don't want to upload your gif to that online service, I'm pretty sure it uses Imagemagick in the background...

Answer (score 1):

There are too many frames. You'll need to reduce the number of frames and adjust the frame delay, and reduce the number of colours.  This shouldn't impact the quality of the animation too much, although it will not be quite as smooth. Here's how:

1. Open the GIF in Photoshop, and make sure the Timeline is visible
2. Select every odd numbered frame by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click them, this will take a while as there are over 400 frames
3. In the Timeline menu, choose *Delete Frame*
4. In the Timeline menu, choose *Select All Frames*
5. Change the frame delay to double the existing delay, from 0.03 to 0.06
6. Do *File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy)*, Choose the "GIF" optimised format, set the number of colours lower, say around 20 or so. Set the dither to 0%
7. Check the estimated file size at the bottom left of the Save for Web dialog. If necessary, adjust the number of colours until the file size is less than 150k

[image]

8. Play the GIF to make sure it still looks OK
9. Hit Save